# How to put an image in a kibana visualization plugin?

Tags: kibana, kibana-5

I want to put an image in my visualization. This is a very static vis.
The html I got so far:

```
<div ng-controller="headerCtrl" ng-app="header-app" id="header">
  <img id="logoImg" src="plugins/vis_header/images/logo.jpg" alt="logo.jpg" />
</div>
```

As I understood the main path to visualization resources is "plugins/name_of_plugin" and kibana will provide access to the "public" folder.
I tried several combinations for the src but none worked, I always get a 404 response.

Is there no way to access images or do I have to handle it another way?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/development-basepath.html

As per documentation  try using kbn-src as well.

Comment: Thanks that helped.